# Laravel 5 stored procedure error

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I am running a stored procedure from my form on submit. However, I keep getting the following error:

> The active result for the query contains no fields.

Below is what I have tried. 
Code to execute SP
`DB::select('EXEC myStored_Procedure');`

I have also tried

```
DB::select('SET NOCOUNT ON;  EXEC myStored_Procedure');
```

But both return the same error. I have also used `Set NOCOUNT ON;` within the stored procedure itself, but with the error still occurs.

My SP works fine and my web page works fine separately, but when I call the SP from the web page it always returns this error.

How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DB::select` expects some data to be returned as a response to the query that was sent to db. You can use `DB::statement` instead, if you don't care about the results sent from db, or if the db doesn't send any:

```
DB::statement('EXEC myStored_Procedure');
```